# Using Octave fft function in c++ application

Tags: c++, fft, octave

I use Octave libraries in my test c++ application.
I have no problems using standart examples like [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html).

The working example:

```
octave_value_list f_arg, f_ret;
f_arg(0) = octave_value(2.5);
f_arg(1) = octave_value(2.6);
f_ret = feval("min",f_arg);
Matrix unis (f_ret(0).matrix_value ());
std::cout << unis;
```

But I dont know how to work with fft function because the input is real massive and output is complex massive.

Now I use the following c++ code:

```
ColumnVector x(4);
x(0) = 2;
x(1) = 3;
x(2) = 4;
x(3) = 4;

octave_value_list x_sensor;
x_sensor(0) = x;

ComplexColumnVector freq_rep;

freq_rep = feval("fft", x_sensor(0));
```

It does not work. The question is how can I get the result of fft (massive of image and real parts) and abs(fft)?

Comment: GNU Octave is free software, UTSL! Have a look at libinterp/corefcn/fft.cc and liboctave/numeric/oct-fftw.cc/h